# CSS how to style the "content"/"background" attribute of a custom checkbox tick sign?

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I have created a custom checkbox, all works fine. I would like to know if there's an option to style\manipulate the `content` or `background` attribute. I used a custom tick sign but it sits too much at the bottom, how can I **raise it several pixels up**?

Desired result:

[image]

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39qkjs6k/)

HTML:

```
        <input type='checkbox' value='valuable4' id="valuable4"/>
        <label for="valuable4">
            <span></span>
        </label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

label span
{
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;

    left: 107px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label span
{
    content: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png") no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style checkbox using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: I think you mean to use `background:` instead of `content:`

Comment: No. I already styled the checkbox, I need to style one specific attribute of it. It doesnt matter, `content` or `background`, I still need to raise that element few pixels up.

Comment: `span` elements don't have `content` properties as such, pseudo-elements do.[**content @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content)

Comment: OK, how can I style\move\manipulate the `background` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now this should be exactly what you are looking for. You can safely omit the `<span>`, it is not needed.

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
label {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 107px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:after {
    background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    content:" ";
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 30px;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: -4px;
    top: -8px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39qkjs6k/5/

What's happening here? Basically, you create a pseudo element (which is available on most html elements) `:after` which you apply the `background` to (this replaces the `<span>` you used before). You position it relatively inside its parent `<label>` `right: -4px; top: -8px;`. With the checkbox unchecked, it has `opacity: 0;`, so it's fully transparent, making it invisible. Next to a `:checked` checkbox, it gets `opacity: 1;`, making it fully visible. The `transition-duration: 0.2s;` makes sure that all changes in transitionable properties is being done in a smooth animation rather than just abruptly changing.

Comment: Final edit, added a comprehensive explanation for what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this as a pseudo-element and the label.

You can use the label as the base state of the 'checkbox` and then apply a pseudo-element **on top** of the label using absolute positioning.

The pseudo-element can be moved into the right position by using the top/left values as required

```
label {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    left: 107px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:-8px;
    left:8px
}
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
label {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 107px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  border-color: Red;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: url("https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basicset/tick_64.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: -8px;
  left: 8px
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' value='valuable4' id="valuable4" />
<label for="valuable4">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what exactly you've added to the existing code and how it affected the final result?

Comment: Added a brief explanation. You really don't need the span at all...especially since it's empty.